# Globals in environment variable declaration in a declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to use globals to set the value of an environment variable in a declarative pipeline?

The following example works as expected.

```
#!groovy
@Library("SomeSharedLibrary@1.0.0") _
pipeline {
    agent none
    environment {
        FOO = "World"
        BAR = "Hello ${FOO}!"
    }
    stages{
        stage("Simple test") {
            steps {
                echo BAR //prints "Hello World!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following code fails. It uses a global `var` defined in `ASharedLibrary`.

```
#!groovy
@Library("ASharedLibrary@1.0.0") _
pipeline {
    agent none
    environment {
        FOO = "World"
        BAR = glovalvar.greet(FOO)
    }
    stages{
        stage("Simple test") {
            steps {
                echo BAR //fails telling that BAR is not defined.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the previous example, if I replace `FOO` by the actual value in the , `BAR` takes proper value.

Any idea? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Given that the pipeline syntax supports this: What if you explicitely type `FOO` with `String FOO` = ... or the argument with `...greet(FOO.toString())`? P.S.: There's something missing after "_in the_", isn't it?

Comment: You are sure `glovalvar` is no typo?

Comment: @StefanHanke I was thinking the same but shouldn't the pipeline fail earlier then with `'glovalvar' not found` or the like?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Jenkins 2.67 silently ignores the error, and does not define the variable. The error is thrown when it is used.

Comment: @StefanHanke I see. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @StefanHanke @GeroldBroser `globalvar` is defined inside the library. If instead glovalvar.greet we use `sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo ${FOO}")` it fails the same way. It seems that Jenkins does not know how access to `FOO` when it is called in a method or in a step at `enviroment` section. The annoying part is that it fails silently until you use the variable in the steps section

Comment: Have you tried ```globalvar.greet("${FOO}")``` ??

Comment: @ChrisCogdon, we tried it, same result.  No error but the variable is not set. We end up doing a custom step in a shared library to set env. vars. or using scripted pipelines.